# Want to make db layer generic and not tied to spring's JdbcDaoSupport

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Current I have a seperate maven module for my database access, all my DAO classes inherit from:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> extends JdbcDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T> {
}
```

My maven module has a spring dependancy:

```
org.springframework spring-orm
```

So a typical Dao class looks like:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User> implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public void insert(User user) {
        getJdbcTemplate().update("insert into users(...)...");
    }
}
```

My Dao's get autowired with the dataSource bean.

**Can I make this generic somehow so I can continue to use it in my spring MVC application, yet it will work if I need to use this library in a cron job service type environment?**  (without having to bring in spring's application context into the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start to observe the following:

- You have a `GenericDao<T>` which means that you can have different implementations.
- Currently, you have `GenericDaoImpl<T> extends JdbcDaoSupport` which means that you cannot use in the other environment you described without any application context unless you prepare all the object in a manual fashion.

So my suggestion is:

- Allow `GenericDao<T> extends org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations`
- Develop an `AbstractGenericDao<T> implements GenericDao<T>` to bring the abstract general functionality you need.
- Develop a `MyEnvGenericDao<T> extends AbstractGenericDao<T>` that is responsible to provide a *data source* and underlying implementation of different methods you need; could be using a direct Hibernate/OpenJPA implementation to directly executing the queries.
- Develop a `SpringGenericDao<T> extends JdbcDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T>` that comes is already with a `getJdbcTemplate()` to perform the operations you need and is delegated to Spring JDBC template. In this scenario, you need to delegate the operations to `JdbcDaoSupport.getJdbcTemplate()`.

Related to Maven, then you can actually have different modules for `MyEnv` and `Spring` implementations but both with one parent to have access to `GenericDao<T>` interface.